# Looping over a dictionary to make multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, dict1, and I am wanting to find a way to loop through it to isolate all the values for shepherds, collies, and poodles. I apologize a head of time if my syntax is off. I am still learning about dictionaries!

```
dict1 = {
'Bob VS Sarah': {
    'shepherd': 1,
    'collie': 5,
    'poodle': 8
},
'Bob VS Ann': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 1
},
'Bob VS Jen': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Sarah VS Bob': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 4
},
'Sarah VS Ann': {
    'shepherd': 4,
    'collie': 6,
    'poodle': 3
},
'Sarah VS Jen': {
    'shepherd': 1,
    'collie': 5,
    'poodle': 8
},
'Jen VS Bob': {
    'shepherd': 4,
    'collie': 8,
    'poodle': 1
},
'Jen VS Sarah': {
    'shepherd': 7,
    'collie': 9,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Jen VS Ann': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 7,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Ann VS Bob': {
    'shepherd': 6,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 5
},
'Ann VS Sarah': {
    'shepherd': 0,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 4
},
'Ann VS Jen': {
    'shepherd': 2,
    'collie': 8,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Bob VS Bob': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Sarah VS Sarah': {
    'shepherd': 3,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 2
},
'Ann VS Ann': {
    'shepherd': 13,
    'collie': 2,
    'poodle': 4
},
'Jen VS Jen': {
    'shepherd': 9,
    'collie': 7,
    'poodle': 2
 }
}
```

This is what I want, for example, but to be able to loop through to make a dictionary for each dog:

dict_shepherd = {'shepherd': 1,3,3,3,4,1,4,7,3,6,0,2,3,3,13,9}

Note: I still have not touched base with pandas and prefer help without using them :) I will get to them one day.

Comment: one problem with this approach is that a `dict` has no order, so your list might not be in the same order as you wrote. does the order matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it in general case for a variable number of keys in sub-dicts with a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

dict1 = # your dictionary of dictionaries here, removed to shorten the presented code

d = defaultdict(list)
for sub_dict in dict1.values():
    for key, value in sub_dict.items():
        d[key].append(value)

pprint(dict(d))
```

Which would produce:

```
{'collie': [2, 7, 8, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 9, 2, 2, 7],
 'poodle': [2, 2, 1, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2],
 'shepherd': [3, 9, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 7, 0, 13, 3]}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make separate dictionaries instead of one?

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_shepherd = {'shepherd': []}
for name in dict1:
    dict_shepherd['shepherd'].append(dict1['shepherd'])
```

It's worth noting that standard dictionaries don't enforce any ordering of their contents, so looping through the items might not yield them in the same order as they are listed in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get all the lists in one line using dictionary and list comprehensions:

```
ds = {type: [val[type] for val in dict1.values()] for type in ['shepherd', 'collie', 'poodle']}

# {'collie': [2, 7, 8, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 9, 2, 2, 7],
#  'poodle': [2, 2, 1, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2],
#  'shepherd': [3, 9, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 7, 0, 13, 3]}
```

However, the lists are in no particular order because a `dict` has no order.

Answer (score 1):

You can user defaultdict as follow

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'Bob VS Sarah': {'shepherd': 1,'collie': 5,'poodle': 8},
 'Bob VS Ann': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 2,'poodle': 1},
 'Bob VS Jen': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 2,'poodle': 2},
 'Sarah VS Bob': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 2,'poodle': 4},
 'Sarah VS Ann': {'shepherd': 4,'collie': 6,'poodle': 3},
 'Sarah VS Jen': {'shepherd': 1,'collie': 5,'poodle': 8},
 'Jen VS Bob': {'shepherd': 4,'collie': 8,'poodle': 1},
 'Jen VS Sarah': {'shepherd': 7,'collie': 9,'poodle': 2},
 'Jen VS Ann': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 7,'poodle': 2},
 'Ann VS Bob': {'shepherd': 6,'collie': 2,'poodle': 5},
 'Ann VS Sarah': {'shepherd': 0,'collie': 2,'poodle': 4},
 'Ann VS Jen': {'shepherd': 2,'collie': 8,'poodle': 2},
 'Bob VS Bob': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 2,'poodle': 2},
 'Sarah VS Sarah': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 2,'poodle': 2},
 'Ann VS Ann': {'shepherd': 13,'collie': 2,'poodle': 4},
 'Jen VS Jen': {'shepherd': 9,'collie': 7,'poodle': 2}}


def iter_dict(dict_, result=defaultdict(list)): # mutable as default value ot reuse result over the recursion
    for k, v in dict_.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iter_dict(v)
        else:
            result[k].append(v)
    return result

print(iter_dict(dict1))
```

That will produce a dict with all expected results

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'shepherd': [3, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7], 'collie': [2, 8, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9], 'poodle': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]})
```